# How do I delete a tree with an inconsistant branching factor up to 30,40

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree, nodes

I know how to delete an entire tree node by node if the tree has an maximum branching factor of 2. Basically going to the right as far as you can and then trying to go to the left. Until you reach a point where both right and left ptr = NULL. I don't really know how to do this in code if the tree has an maximum branching factor of say 40.

Here's the code I have for deleting and finding the highest depth of the tree.

```
int FindDepth(Node* root, bool GoingRight, int Depth = 0, int DepthCompare = 0) {
    if (GoingRight) {
        // If we have reached an end
        if (root->right == NULL) {if (Depth > DepthCompare)DepthCompare = Depth; }

        // If space continue going right
        else DepthCompare = FindDepth(root->right, true, Depth + 1, DepthCompare);

        // Time for going left
        GoingRight = false;
    }

    if (!GoingRight) {
        // If we have reached an end
        if (root->left == NULL) {if (Depth > DepthCompare)DepthCompare = Depth; }

        // If space try going right
        else DepthCompare = FindDepth(root->left, true, Depth + 1, DepthCompare);
    }

    delete root;
    return DepthCompare;
}
```

Any tips if I'd have a node with a maximum of 40 children.

Comment: How are you planning to keep references to child nodes in case of 40 children? In array, vector or something else?

Comment: And do you need only to delete a tree or to calculate its depth as well?

Comment: @KonstantinMurugov I am going to keep refrences of the 40 children. And I'm not sure yet how I'm going to save them. A vector sounds nice. Previously I've used an array of pointers where the array size is the maximum number of branches. And I do not need to calculate it's depth aswell although that would be useful

Answer (score 0):

Applying **Depth-First-Search** looks handy in here. You simply add every node's children into a stack, and while the stack is not empty, you pop a node and do the same for it, until you reach a leaf node that you can delete.

A nice implementation in C++ from geeksforgeeks [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-depth-first-traversal/).

The only differences here, is that you are applying this to a Tree, so no cycles to worry about. You should reach a leaf node straight-forward, which you can delete safely.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need only delete a tree, and you're keeping references to children, for example, in arrays, you can write very straightforward code:

```
const int BranchingFactor = 40;
struct Node
{
  Node * Children[BranchingFactor];  
};

void DeleteSubTree(Node * root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        for (int childNumber = 0; childNumber < BranchingFactor; childNumber++)
            DeleteSubTree(root->Children[childNumber]);
        delete root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! I've tried that but it failed due to poor code. And I was thinking of trying it again. But you've straight up given me the code in it's simplest way although it's pretty simple I somehow managed to make some stupid mistake in my previous code. I'm still thinking if I should use the Node * Childs[Branchingfactor]; due to it making unnecessary pointers that I won't use. Because some nodes may need 30children and some 80 and some just 8.

Comment: Then it's also quite simply to replace arrays with vectors.

Comment: Maybe you'd better show us that previous code of yours.

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to delete an entire tree node by node if the tree has an maximum branching factor of 2. Basically going to the right as far as you can and then trying to go to the left. Until you reach a point where both right and left ptr = NULL.

For a maximum branching factor of whatever, only two changes are needed:

Basically going to the right as far as you can and then trying to go to **the second-right, third-right, ..., last-right (a.k.a. the left)**. Until you reach a point where **all** ptr == NULL.

I would not try to wedge these changes into your code, though. That code has so many hardcoded assumptions that it might be better to restart fresh. *(For example, making `GoingRight` a `bool` assumes that there are only two choices. On the other hand, `GoingRight` is not all that useful since it is always passed in as `true` and always set to `false` right before checking `if(!GoingRight)`.)* Think in terms of looping instead of writing out the cases one after the other (i.e. instead of go-right followed by go-left). The way the tree stores pointers to its children should help guide your code.